# Getting error while installing pip on Windows 10

Tags: python-2.7, pip, easy-install

I am not a Windows user, I have got Windows 10 computer for testing I am trying to install pip but I am getting this error:

```
C:\Python27\Lib>python C:\Python27\get-pip.py
Collecting pip
c:\users\lattep~1\appdata\local\temp\tmpglpkrn\pip.zip\pip\_vendor\urllib3\util\ssl_.py:339: SNIMissingWarning: An HTTPS request has been made, but the SNI (Subject Name Indication) extension to TLS is not available on this platform. This may cause the server to present an incorrect TLS certificate, which can cause validation failures. You can upgrade to a newer version of Python to solve this. For more information, see https://urllib3.readthedocs.io/en/latest/advanced-usage.html#ssl-warnings
c:\users\lattep~1\appdata\local\temp\tmpglpkrn\pip.zip\pip\_vendor\urllib3\util\ssl_.py:137: InsecurePlatformWarning: A true SSLContext object is not available. This prevents urllib3 from configuring SSL appropriately and may cause certain SSL connections to fail. You can upgrade to a newer version of Python to solve this. For more information, see https://urllib3.readthedocs.io/en/latest/advanced-usage.html#ssl-warnings
  Retrying (Retry(total=4, connect=None, read=None, redirect=None, status=None)) after connection broken by 'SSLError(SSLError(1, '_ssl.c:499: error:1407742E:SSL routines:SSL23_GET_SERVER_HELLO:tlsv1 alert protocol version'),)': /simple/pip/
c:\users\lattep~1\appdata\local\temp\tmpglpkrn\pip.zip\pip\_vendor\urllib3\util\ssl_.py:137: InsecurePlatformWarning: A true SSLContext object is not available. This prevents urllib3 from configuring SSL appropriately and may cause certain SSL connections to fail. You can upgrade to a newer version of Python to solve this. For more information, see https://urllib3.readthedocs.io/en/latest/advanced-usage.html#ssl-warnings
  Retrying (Retry(total=3, connect=None, read=None, redirect=None, status=None)) after connection broken by 'SSLError(SSLError(1, '_ssl.c:499: error:1407742E:SSL routines:SSL23_GET_SERVER_HELLO:tlsv1 alert protocol version'),)': /simple/pip/
c:\users\lattep~1\appdata\local\temp\tmpglpkrn\pip.zip\pip\_vendor\urllib3\util\ssl_.py:137: InsecurePlatformWarning: A true SSLContext object is not available. This prevents urllib3 from configuring SSL appropriately and may cause certain SSL connections to fail. You can upgrade to a newer version of Python to solve this. For more information, see https://urllib3.readthedocs.io/en/latest/advanced-usage.html#ssl-warnings
  Retrying (Retry(total=2, connect=None, read=None, redirect=None, status=None)) after connection broken by 'SSLError(SSLError(1, '_ssl.c:499: error:1407742E:SSL routines:SSL23_GET_SERVER_HELLO:tlsv1 alert protocol version'),)': /simple/pip/
c:\users\lattep~1\appdata\local\temp\tmpglpkrn\pip.zip\pip\_vendor\urllib3\util\ssl_.py:137: InsecurePlatformWarning: A true SSLContext object is not available. This prevents urllib3 from configuring SSL appropriately and may cause certain SSL connections to fail. You can upgrade to a newer version of Python to solve this. For more information, see https://urllib3.readthedocs.io/en/latest/advanced-usage.html#ssl-warnings
  Retrying (Retry(total=1, connect=None, read=None, redirect=None, status=None)) after connection broken by 'SSLError(SSLError(1, '_ssl.c:499: error:1407742E:SSL routines:SSL23_GET_SERVER_HELLO:tlsv1 alert protocol version'),)': /simple/pip/
c:\users\lattep~1\appdata\local\temp\tmpglpkrn\pip.zip\pip\_vendor\urllib3\util\ssl_.py:137: InsecurePlatformWarning: A true SSLContext object is not available. This prevents urllib3 from configuring SSL appropriately and may cause certain SSL connections to fail. You can upgrade to a newer version of Python to solve this. For more information, see https://urllib3.readthedocs.io/en/latest/advanced-usage.html#ssl-warnings
  Retrying (Retry(total=0, connect=None, read=None, redirect=None, status=None)) after connection broken by 'SSLError(SSLError(1, '_ssl.c:499: error:1407742E:SSL routines:SSL23_GET_SERVER_HELLO:tlsv1 alert protocol version'),)': /simple/pip/
c:\users\lattep~1\appdata\local\temp\tmpglpkrn\pip.zip\pip\_vendor\urllib3\util\ssl_.py:137: InsecurePlatformWarning: A true SSLContext object is not available. This prevents urllib3 from configuring SSL appropriately and may cause certain SSL connections to fail. You can upgrade to a newer version of Python to solve this. For more information, see https://urllib3.readthedocs.io/en/latest/advanced-usage.html#ssl-warnings
  Could not fetch URL https://pypi.org/simple/pip/: There was a problem confirming the ssl certificate: HTTPSConnectionPool(host='pypi.org', port=443): Max retries exceeded with url: /simple/pip/ (Caused by SSLError(SSLError(1, '_ssl.c:499: error:1407742E:SSL routines:SSL23_GET_SERVER_HELLO:tlsv1 alert protocol version'),)) - skipping
  Could not find a version that satisfies the requirement pip (from versions: )
No matching distribution found for pip
```

I have manually installed urllib3 and setuptools that got into site-packages, so I tested:

```
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> import urllib3
>>> import setuptools
>>>
```

and I can import but cannot install pip still.

Comment: What Python version? `python --version`

Comment: `C:\Users\LattePanda>python --version`
`Python 2.7`

Comment: Well, just `2.7` is not enough, I expected the third number. Ok, you probably need to upgrade Python if it's lower than `2.7.9`; upgrade to latest `2.7`. I suspect you have SSL problem and you need to upgrade Python to connect to PyPI and install `pip`.

Comment: had similar problem..fixed it by uninstalling python and installing 2.7.15